# cannot change href attribute of a hyperlink using jQuery twice

Tags: jquery

I have the below code which is placed in the header and executed on every page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*="/replace"]').each(function(){ 
        var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); 
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("/replace", "/"+val); //val is retrieved from local storage
        $(this).attr("href", newUrl); 
    });
});
```

I have another code executed in certain pages to push the val into local storage and replace the new URL afterward on a press of a button

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    localstorage.push(val)
    $('a[href*="/replace"]').each(function(){ 
        var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); 
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("/replace", "/"+val); //val already pushed to local
        $(this).attr("href", newUrl); 
    });
});
```

It seems that "replace" won't be executed twice. My question: is there any alternative to replace the URL more than once?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace multiple times, you can pass a `RegExp` as [the first argument to `.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and use [the global modifier (`g`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global). Demo:

```js
const str = 'abc/replace jkl/replace xyz'

console.log(str.replace('/replace', '@@'))
console.log(str.replace(/\/replace/g, '@@')) // notice I escaped the '/'
```

You could also use [`str.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), but the browser support for this method is not as good, so YMMV.

Comment: it did work, I found other issues in the code...
thanks for the support!